# ReactJS - update user at state array

Tags: reactjs, state

I have this USERS list in STATE,

```
{
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  },....
```

I want to find by id and save one USER in a separate STATE for updating
and then add it back to the list.

Thanks

Comment: What have you already done, share your code

Comment: Are you using a class component or are you saving a state into a hook? Why do you need to put the user in a new state to modify it? Put code examples and share more details on how it should work!

Answer (score 0):

## I assume you are using functional component

## your state

```js
const userlist = [ {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit",
    "body": "quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "qui est esse",
    "body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 3,
    "title": "ea molestias quasi exercitationem repellat qui ipsa sit aut",
    "body": "et iusto sed quo iure\nvoluptatem occaecati omnis eligendi aut ad\nvoluptatem doloribus vel accusantium quis pariatur\nmolestiae porro eius odio et labore et velit aut"
  }]

const [ users, setUsers ] = use state(userlist)
const [ selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers ] = useState([])
```

## function that stores the value of selected user when clicks a button

```js
const addUser = (title, body, userId, id)=>{
    newUser = { title: title, body: body, userId: userId, id: id }
    setSelectedUsers((data)=> return [ ...data, newUser ])
}
```

## Whenever the user clicks a button, it adds that user to the list

```js
{users.map((user, index)=>{ return(
<div>
<h1> {user.title} </h1>
<p>{user.body}</p>
<button onClick={()=> addUser(user.title, user.body, user.userId, user.id)}>add </button>
</div>
)
})}
```